# How to fix this error in geonode

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu

when we run this command :

```
:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonode/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES# geonode makemessages --all
```

Get this error message :

> CommandError: This script should be run from the Django Git tree or
>   your project or app tree. If you did indeed run it from the Git
>   checkout or your project or application, maybe you are just missing
>   the conf/locale (in the django tree) or locale (for project and
>   application) directory? It is not created automatically, you have to
>   create it by hand if you want to enable i18n for your project or
>   application.

could you please help for me to solve this problem...

Comment: could you provide project directory structure?!!you need to have locale folder in project root folder